# Jetty and apache same host

Tags: java, wordpress, apache, jetty-9

I have a vps from which I would like to serve a wordpress site, and a Tapestry5 webapp.

I usually use jetty for hosting my webapps, and apache for wordpress, but I am struggling to find a rough guide on how to configure both of these to play nicely together on the same host.

My aim is to have:

```
blog.foo.com -> The apache server hosting wordpress

foo.com -> The jetty webapp.
```

I want to avoid having port numbers showing in the address bar, so ideally I am thinking perhaps jetty or apache can check the URL, spot which one should respond, and forward the request appropriately. Since i'm new to this area, I'm struggling to find a guide (or rather.. know which guides to even look for) to achieve this.

My questions are:

- Is this possible?
- Roughly how does one go about setting this up - is there a specific part of either of the documentations which will help me? Which one of these should be listening on port 80 (assuming they can't both be on that port)?

Comment: You need a reverse proxy.

Comment: While not for Jetty, [this link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/proxy-howto.html) walks you through the process for Tomcat.  It should be very similar.